# Sequence of letters to sequence of numbers R

Tags: r, string, numbers

I have a data frame that looks like:

```
df <- as.data.frame(c("AAA", "AAB", "AAC", "BBA"))
df

1                           AAA
2                           AAB
3                           AAC
4                           BBA
```

And I want to obtain something like:

```
1                           111
2                           112
3                           113
4                           221
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `base R`, we can use `chartr`

```
df[[1]] <- chartr("ABC", "123", df[[1]])
df[[1]]
#[1] "111" "112" "113" "221"
```

---

In case if the values that replaces have more than one character, then a general solution is `str_replace_all` - use a named key/value vector to match and replace

```
library(stringr)
 str_replace_all(df[[1]],   setNames(c("1", "2", "3"), c("A", "B", "C")))
[1] "111" "112" "113" "221"
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use `LETTERS` from base R and a named vector to convert the letters to their respective numbers.

```
libary(tidyverse) 

map_chr(strsplit(df$x, ""), ~ str_flatten(setNames(seq_along(LETTERS), LETTERS)[.]))
[1] "111" "112" "113" "221"
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is using `gsubfn` to replace the letters with their number:

```
library(gsubfn)
v <- setNames(seq_along(LETTERS), LETTERS)
transform(df, numbers = gsubfn("(.)", as.list(v), df[[1]]))
```

Output:

```
  c..AAA....AAB....AAC....BBA.. numbers
1                           AAA     111
2                           AAB     112
3                           AAC     113
4                           BBA     221
```

Comment: Edited the code. Thanks to great suggestion from @G.Grothendieck

Answer (score 1):

Here is another base R trick using `utf8ToInt`

```
> v <- c("AAA", "AAB", "AAC", "BBA")

> sapply(v, function(x) crossprod(utf8ToInt(x) - 64, 10^((nchar(x):1) - 1)))
AAA AAB AAC BBA 
111 112 113 221
```